# Relationship with parameter then use contains in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Have the next code working properly:

```
$system_breeds = SystemsGroup::find($group_id)->breeds;

$breeds = Breed::select('id', 'breed')->orderBy('breed')->get()->transform(function ($breed) use ($system_breeds) {
    if ($system_breeds->contains($breed)) {
        $breed->active = true;
    }
    return $breed;
});
```

On every breed that exists on the system_breeds I'm adding an active property as true.

What I want to do now, is something like this:

```
$system_breeds = SystemsGroup::where('id',$group_id)->with(['breeds' => function($q) use ($section_id){
   $q->where('group_section_id', $section_id);
}])->get();
```

So, add a where filter on the relationship. But the "contains" doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not much clear, look you want to filter and get related models, if so try like this.

```
$system_breeds = SystemsGroup::find($group_id)->breeds()->where('group_section_id',$section_id)->get();
```

Comment: nope, what I want to do is to change the first "$system_breeds = SystemsGroup::find($group_id)->breeds;" with "$system_breeds = SystemsGroup::where('id',$group_id)->with(['breeds' => function($q) use ($section_id){
   $q->where('group_section_id', $section_id);
}])->get();"
That means to use a conditional in the relationship query (where('group_section_id', $section_id))

Comment: check now, I updated the answer, still am not clear what you wanted ;(

Answer (score 0):

I guess $system_breeds is an array. Try converting it into a collection using

```
collect($system_breeds)
```

Once it is an instance of Collection class, 'contains' method should work.

Comment: No, my $system_breeds is an object